# XML to JSON Conversion with Conditions

Tags: java, json, xml

Wanted to covert an xml String to Json and I am doing it as below.

XML which has to be converted

```
<Item>
    <Property name="Description" value="Description 1"/>
    <Property name="EffDate" value="01/05/2017"/>
    <Property name="ExpDate" value="12/31/9999"/>
    <Property name="Status" value="Launched"/>
</Item>
```

I have created a Class for the xml as below.

```
public class Context {  
    @XmlElement(name = "Item")
    private List<Item> offer;
}

public class Item { 
    @XmlElement(name = "Property")
    private List<Property> properties;
}

public class Property {
    @XmlAttribute
    private String name;

    @XmlAttribute
    private String value;
}
```

I am using Gson libraries to convert this Java object to Json - g.toJson.

Comverted JSON -

```
   "offer": [{
   "properties": [{
                "name": "Description",
                "value": "Description 1"
            },
            {
                "name": "EffDate",
                "value": "01/05/2017"
            },
            {
                "name": "ExpDate",
                "value": "12/31/9999"
            },
            {
                "name": "Status",
                "value": "Launched"
            }]
         }]
```

But we wanted to convert the JSON as below -

```
"offer": [{
     "Description" : "Description 1",
     "EffDate":"01/05/2017",
     "ExpDate": "12/31/9999",
     "Status": "Launched"
    }]
```

Is there a way to convert the properties name and value as Item class properties.?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this link: https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java This is a JSON Helper class that can convert XML to JSON for example:

```
public class Main {

    public static int PRETTY_PRINT_INDENT_FACTOR = 4;
    public static String TEST_XML_STRING =
        "<?xml version=\"1.0\" ?><test attrib=\"moretest\">Turn this to JSON</test>";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            JSONObject xmlJSONObj = XML.toJSONObject(TEST_XML_STRING);
            String jsonPrettyPrintString = xmlJSONObj.toString(PRETTY_PRINT_INDENT_FACTOR);
            System.out.println(jsonPrettyPrintString);
        } catch (JSONException je) {
            System.out.println(je.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Is there a way to convert the properties name and value as Item class properties.? As showed above

Answer (score 0):

It is possible using  [FasterXML](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonSerializer.html) library. where you can write your custom logic for generating XML and JSON. By overriding `serialize` of `JsonSerializer` class.

**Need to write Serializer like :**

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonSerializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ContextSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Context> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(Context t, JsonGenerator jg, SerializerProvider sp) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        jg.writeStartObject();
        jg.writeArrayFieldStart("offer");
        for (Item i : t.offer) {
            jg.writeStartObject();
            for (Property property : i.properties) {
                jg.writeStringField(property.name, property.value);
            }
            jg.writeEndObject();
        }
        jg.writeEndArray();
        jg.writeEndObject();
    }
}
```

**For convert:**

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude.Include;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.module.SimpleModule;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException, JsonProcessingException {
        Context c = new Context();
        List<Item> offer = new ArrayList<>();
        Item pr = new Item();
        pr.properties = new ArrayList<>();

        Property p = new Property();
        p.name = "asdf";
        p.value = "va1";
        pr.properties.add(p);

        p = new Property();
        p.name = "asdf1";
        p.value = "va11";
        pr.properties.add(p);

        offer.add(pr);
        c.offer = offer;
        try {
            SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
            module.addSerializer(Context.class, new ContextSerializer());
            ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            objectMapper.registerModule(module);
            objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_DEFAULT);
            String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(c);
            System.out.println(json);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(""+e);
        }
    }
}
```

**O/P JSON :** (Provided O/P JSON is wrong in your question if you give the name to the list("offer") then it always inside object [link](http://json.org/))

```
{
    "offer": [{
            "asdf": "va1",
            "asdf1": "va11"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Maven Dependency for package is:**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.0.pr3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.0.pr3</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **Java 8** or later, you should check out my open source library: [unXml](https://github.com/tajakobsen/unxml). unXml basically maps from Xpaths to Json-attributes.

It's available on [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cunxml).

*Example*

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode;
import com.nerdforge.unxml.factory.ParsingFactory;
import com.nerdforge.unxml.parsers.Parser;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;

public class Parser {
  public ObjectNode parseXml(String xml){
    Parsing parsing = ParsingFactory.getInstance().create();
    Document document = parsing.xml().document(xml);

    Parser<ObjectNode> parser = parsing.obj("/")
        .attribute("offer", parsing.arr("/Item")
            .attribute("Description", "Property[@name='Description']/@value")
            .attribute("EffDate", "Property[@name='EffDate']/@value")
            .attribute("ExpDate", "Property[@name='ExpDate']/@value")
            .attribute("Status", "Property[@name='Status']/@value")
        )
        .build();

    ObjectNode result = parser.apply(document);
    return result;
  }
}
```

It will return a [Jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHome) `ObjectNode`, with the following json:

```
{
  "offer": [
    {
      "Status": "Launched",
      "Description": "Description 1",
      "ExpDate": "12/31/9999",
      "EffDate": "01/05/2017"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may convert xml to a map, modify it and then convert to a json. [Underscore-java](https://github.com/javadev/underscore-java) library has static methods `U.fromXml(xml)` and `U.toJson(json)`. I am the maintainer of the project.